# Why is octave constantly stat-ing files?

Tags: octave

This is a very old installation of octave, 3.05, but it is standard on centos-5, which still exists in many production environments.  When I strace octave, I see that it is constantly calling stat on the same files over and over. It must be spending half its time just stat-ing the same files. Here is a sample:

```
stat("/usr/local/share/octave/3.0.5/m/path", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/octave/3.0.5/m/plot", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/octave/3.0.5/m/pkg", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/octave/3.0.5/m/sparse", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/octave/3.0.5/m/control", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/octave/3.0.5/m/control/obsolete", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/local/share/octave/3.0.5/m/control/hinf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

That doesn't really give the full flavor because its many more and the same ones over and over. It happens in bursts.  Why is it doing this and how can I make it stop? Or at least make it do it once instead of constantly.

Comment: What files is it constantly parsing? Is that the ones from the functions being used? If so, my guess would be that it does this so it doesn't have to parse the file again in case it was not modified. But Octave 3.0.5 is a really really old version.

Comment: it seems like it is stating pretty much every file in its path, plus the current directory. Of course it needs to do that at least once to look for code, but I want it to do once per invocation.  I'm not sure if it still does that in newer octaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! Octave is stat-ing the files to check the modification timestamp to see if they have changed since the last time it stat-ed them. This can be disabled and should improve performance, regardless of the octave version.

From http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Files.html:

If you know that your own function files will not change while you are running Octave, you can improve performance by calling `ignore_function_time_stamp ("all")`, so that Octave will ignore the time stamps for all function files. Passing "system" to this function resets the default behavior.

Comment: I think "improve performance" is subjective. If it is a large program, making many internal function calls, it may improve performance. I tried it with one of my programs and it actually seemed to increase the run time by 0.5 seconds on a program that takes about 1 minute, 10 seconds to run. I only did about 6 runs each with and without the `ignore_function_time_stamp ("all")` but I used the same input data each time.

Comment: I don't know the internals of octave well, but it seems to me that there should be strictly fewer system calls, which are relatively expensive operations, if this is set to all.  Maybe there is some kind of initial penalty? The octave docs also claim this should improve performance.